# Application Class Security

Tags: php, object-oriented, security, classes, php5

Is my Application.php class secure for continuing development?

The Application.php acts as a registry for the whole application. I tried not to rewrite already working code that is being pulled from Zend Framework and PhalconPHP, but allow myself to have freedom with using frameworks within my web application.

Also, please read the comments about each function. That should explain exactly what it is doing.

Also, I try to protect as many functions, and variables as possible over throwing a `private` on them and reduce expandability.

```
    <?php

    /**
     *   Package:  Core Application
     *   Authors:  Traven, Todd
     *   Version:  1.o.0
    **/

    /**
     *   Base QuadCMS Core Application Class  
     *   Sets up the environment as necessary and acts as the registry
     *   for QuadCMS and the Core Application.
    **/

    class Application extends PhalconPHP {

        //  Stores if QuadCMS has been initialized.
        protected $_initialized = false;

        //  Provides a few configuration options for the
        //  initialization process.
        protected static $_initConfig = array(
            'undoMagicQuotes' => true,
            'setMemoryLimit' => true,
            'resetOutputBuffering' => true
            );

        //  Unused currently
        protected $_lazyLoaders = $array();

        /**
         *    Moved to Authentication.php
         *   //  Cache of random data (Binary characters)
         *   protected static $_randomData = '';
        **/

        //  Cache of dynamic classes and what they resolve to
        protected static $_classCache = array();

        //  If true, Exceptions.php will handle PHP errors/warnings/notices
        //  If false, PHP will most likely handle the errors
        protected static $_errorHandler = true;

        //  Controls if QuadCMS is in debug mode
        protected static $_debug;

        //  Current time of the web server (Unix timestamp)
        public static $time = 0;

        // Hostname of the server
        public static $hostname = 'localhost';

        //  Are we using SSL/TSL?
        //  Default is false
        public static $secure = false;

        //  Current printable and human-readable versions
        //  Also, usable for visual display of version
        public static $version   = '1.0.0';
        public static $versionID = '10000100';

        //  Path to the Configuration files
        //  Path to the root directory
        protected $_configPath = '.';
        protected $_rootPath   = '.';

        //  Relative path to the Data directory 
        public static $dataPath = 'data';



        //  Start the application. Sets up the environment.
        public function startApp($configPath = '.', $rootPath = '.', $loadData = true) {
            if($this->_initialized) {
                return;
            }

            if (self::$_initConfig['undoMagicQuotes'] && function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                self::undoMagicQuotes($_GET);
                self::undoMagicQuotes($_POST);
                self::undoMagicQuotes($_COOKIE);
                self::undoMagicQuotes($_REQUEST);
            }

            if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_runtime') && get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
                @set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);
            }

            if (self::$_initConfig['setMemoryLimit']) {
                self::setMemoryLimit(64 * 1024 * 1024);
            }

            if (self::$_initConfig['resetOutputBuffering']) {
                @ini_set('output_buffering', false);
                @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

                if (!@ini_get('output_handler')) {
                    $level = ob_get_level();
                    while ($level) {
                        @ob_end_clean();
                        $newLevel = ob_get_level();
                        if ($newLevel >= $level) {
                            break;
                        }
                        $level = $newLevel;
                    }
                }
            }

            error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT & ~8192);
            set_error_handler(array('Application', 'handlePhpError'));
            set_exception_handler(array('Application', 'handleException'));
            register_shutdown_function(array('Application', 'handleFatalError'));

            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
            self::$time = time();
            self::$hostname = (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? '' : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
            self::$secure = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on');

            $this->_configPath = $configPath;
            $this->_rootPath   = $rootPath;
            $this->addLazyLoader('requestPaths', array($this), 'loadRequestPaths')

            if ($loadData) {
                $this->loadData();
            }

            //  Becomes initialized
            $this->_initialized = true;
        }




        //  Helper function for initialization
        public static function initialize() {
            self::className(__CLASS__);
            self::changeInitConfig($initChanges);
            self::getInstance()->startApp($$this_configPath, $this->_rootPath, $this->_loadData);
        }



        //  Loads the default data for the application
        public function loadData() {
            $config = $this->loadConfig();
            self::set('config', $config);
            self::setDebugMode($config->debug);
            self::$DataPath = (string)$config->DataPath;
        }



        //  Merges changes into the configuration
        public static function mergeChanges(array $changes) {
            if($changes) {
                self::$_initConfig = array_merge(self::_initConfig, $changes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Is my... class secure?" - What exactly are the threats you're afraid of?

Comment: @AlexL I *think* I have the class locked down enough so no one can take advantage of my bad coding (using protected over public or private functions for security)

Comment: Why are you suppressing the errors? Maybe your question is too broad, but I haven't seen anything else wrong with your class.